# How to convert this date with php

Tags: javascript, php

How to convert this date format that is coming from javascript:

`Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)`

These formats are not working

`$date = date('c', strtotime(Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time));`

`$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time));`

The date goes back to 1969

Any insights?

Comment: Is there any way for you to change the way JS delivers this data?

Comment: Should work once you cut of the time zone part written in natural language – `strtotime('Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300')`.

Comment: You fix the javascript code to send date in a parasable format

Comment: @CBroe yes it works, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you should try skip "(Brasilia Standard Time)" in the data submit.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300"));
var_dump($date);
```

I got this result:

> string(19) "2021-03-04 01:00:00"

Edit: If you can 'skip' that string, you can do something like:

```
 $strTime = "Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)";
 $strTime = str_replace($strTime, ""," (Brasilia Standard Time)");
 $date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($strTime));

 var_dump($date);
```

output:

> string(19) "1969-12-31 04:00:00"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the modern DateTime interface and specifying a proper format, rather than having PHP try to guess how to interpret the date string. You can also use the `+` specifier to ignore trailing data rather than having to edit your input in advance.

```php
$string = 'Thu Mar 04 2021 18:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d Y H:i:s T+', $string);

var_dump($date, $date->format('c'));
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-03-04 18:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "-03:00"
}
string(25) "2021-03-04T18:00:00-03:00"
```